# How can I make a fresh install of Ubuntu?

Tags: installation, 13.04

I want to remove Windows 7 from my Toshiba Satellite and do a fresh install of Ubuntu on it. How can I get that done?

Comment: Regret I do not concur. The linked prior answer refers to WUBI which is depreciated, and does not explicitly refer to what the OP wanted, to completely remove Win7.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Ubuntu download Page and get one of the Ubuntu versions. Then download usb universal installer and boot up using a flash or CD. Then after that you have the option while installing to wipe everything and install Ubunut.

-Regards

Answer (score 0):

Follow the [official Ubuntu instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall). In the **Installation Type** screen of the installation, choose the second option, select *Erase disk and install Ubuntu*, then select the hard drive to which you want to install Ubuntu. This will completely erase Windows 7 from your machine.